# When does "copying" a math diagram become plagiarism?

Tags: mathematics, computer-science, plagiarism, graphics

If you copy paste a diagram from a paper/book onto your own work, without permission or attribution, that's plagiarism.

What happens if you see a beautiful diagram about what you want to explain and you replicate it identically without copy pasting?

What if you don't copy it identically but it's still similar (say the colors are different, and the vertices/edges/boxes) have slightly different shapes? For example the original used a 3D blob to explain what a local chart is, and your diagram uses an ellipsoid.

What if you transfer mediums? For example a chalkboard diagram turned into a metafont diagram?

Since there are only so many ways to convey certain mathematical ideas, such as what a bivector is, or how to compute a spline. When do you know where your source of inspiration is too close to your own work that you walked over into plagiarism?

Comment: Do not mix plagiarism and copyright infringement as in your opening.

Comment: @Alchimista I'm a little confused by your comment, this question doesn't seem to mention copyright at all. (And it hasn't been edited)

Comment: @DavidZ The use of the word "permission" implies copyright.

Comment: @DamianYerrick No it doesn't. There are many situations that have nothing to do with copyright and yet involve some kind of grant of permission. I mean, sure, the word "permission" makes some people think of copyright, and there's nothing wrong with that; my point is just that the fact that the OP used the word "permission" is not sufficient to conclude that they meant to ask about copyright.

Comment: If you have to ask here - don't do it. Better safe than sorry, I think.

Comment: "When does “copying” a math diagram become plagiarism?" "without permission or attribution, that's plagiarism." - Question answers itself.... However, you can be sued by anyone for anything. But generally if you don't have any money, aren't making any money, or are not costing them money, it's unlikely... because suing someone costs money.

Comment: @Mazura: I don't think "permission" has anything to do with plagiarism. If you say to someone "Feel free to claim my ideas and my work as your own", and they do so, they have committed plagiarism.

Comment: @DavidZ To me isn't only the opening but the entire question that mixes the two situation. I see why OP is asking for, is quite a recurrent situation in science. Normally one choose to ask for permission fixing the copyright issue, and cite the source in text or caption to avoid plagiarism. Perfect answer is by Spark. - I am not saying what OP is asking for in my comment above. Just that the Q might mix things.

Comment: @Oddthinking - Correct. "without [...] attribution, that's plagiarism." - Without *permission* - that's copyright infringement, depending on how good everyone's lawyers are.

Comment: @Mazura not if it's a fair use though.

Comment: Also agreed. But between this and the comments on Dan's answer, now we're just going in circles, and it doesn't matter anyway because none of us are lawyers and none of this has anything to do with academia.

Comment: Broadly there are two, very different kinds of Copyright. One applies solely to the content and the other solely to the presentation.

If you look at your and the original author's diagrams, how exactly can they be distinguished?

If not at all, that's clearly plagiarism.

If at all then how, please?

Comment: Colors are different, font is different, line widths are different. But because they describe the same underlying mathematical structure the "shape" is essentially the same (a hexagon with a bunch of itnernal connections).

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Paraphrasing Simon Peyton Jones [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/academic-program/give-great-research-talk/), credit is like love. Giving it to more people does not diminish it or you.

Even if you recreated an image yourself, there’s literally no reason to not attribute your inspiration for it (apart from your own ego).

The threshold for plagiarism is vague at times, but if you saw someone’s work, liked it and built upon it, give them credit.

Comment: Giving the credit is not the issue. It's a minimum courtesy. 
But if I did something similar with a code base, or with art, or with a paper, giving credit would not be enough, as just paraphrasing a paper would constitute gross academic misconduct. I am trying to determine how ok it is to reproduce diagrams.

Comment: It’s ok to reproduce diagrams, if you cite the source of inspiration.

Comment: Maybe not. A diagram can sometimes be considered a complete work. Copying it can be copyright violation. Even though it is part of a larger work. You really need to get permission as well as cite it. Fair use doesn’t apply to complete works.

Comment: I guess more diagrams in an academic paper context

Comment: @Makogan "just paraphrasing a paper would constitute gross academic misconduct" - I'd argue that if it's correctly cited and attributed then it probably wouldn't be misconduct. It might not have much value as a peice of work, but because you've been honest about it it *isn't* misconduct.

Comment: @Makogan just cite it as "inspired by" ... and you're good. Now if your entire work is just stuff like that you have a whole nother problem

Comment: "inspired by..." or "adapted from...." is the formulation I see a lot. But you do need to be careful with copywrite - when I was publishing a textbook the publishers were very eagle-eyed about the copying of diagrams, and it costs us a lot of money for every figure we used where the lawyers decided it was too similar.

Comment: @IanSudbery, I'd love to see what you write here as a full answer. The copyright stuff. I think we don't have a complete result here yet.

Comment: I'll try to write it up as a proper answer when I've got a little more time. I didn't include it as a full answer initially as the legal concept copywrite is different to the academic concept of plagerism (although they are obviously connected).

Comment: @DavidW I mean paraphrasing the entire paper, not just a section.

Comment: @Makogan I'd still argue that it isn't plagiarism because there's no dishonesty about what you've done. It may be copyright violation (which is a legal issue, rather than an academic issue) and it may not be publishable or worth many marks when assessed, but provided you haven't misrepresented what it is then it doesn't deserve academic punishment.

Comment: @Makogan As an example: I might translate someone's worth to another language. I might well have to get copyright clearance to do so. However nobody is going to view a properly attributed translation as academic dishonesty or plagiarism and many people might find it useful.

Comment: "But if I did something similar with a code base, or with art, or with a paper, giving credit would not be enough" – That's not true (in the context of your question). Copying something and giving all due credit is *never* plagiarism. It may be copyright infringement, but your question is about plagiarism, not copyright infringement. If you meant to ask about copyright infringement, please edit your question accordingly.

Comment: @Makogan : there are cases where paraphrasing a large part of a paper is *crucial*, for example when your paper is about optimizing an already existing complex method. But to do that, you first have to describe what that original method does, then going through all the steps, and describe what the advantages and disadvantages of certain changes to those steps are.

Answer (score 10):

I am not a lawyer. However, this is how it presents itself to me:

I think it is necessary to distinguish the "citation" from the "copyright" aspect:

**Citation**: A complete recreation of a diagram to convey a (semi-)formal idea is like the reproduction of a formula. I would not assume copyright violation applies here, but it definitely needs to be cited if there is any original contribution in the diagram (e.g. it is the first time that something is visualised in a particular way etc.) rather than a well-known and -used standard diagram.

In Greek mathematics, diagrams often took the role that formulas take today, and this is still often the case today: exact sequences, Feynman diagrams, Organic Chemistry etc. all fall into this category. In short, if your diagram falls into a category equivalent to any of these, recreate and cite.

**Copyright**: If the diagram itself is not original, but you are copying the style, possibly colour scheme etc., then recreating it may fall under copyright violation and you need permission from the copyright holder.

Comment: Scientific citations and copyright aren't the same by a long shot though...

Comment: This is an important idea to get across to the OP. Data, itself, can't be copyrighted, and so trivial representations of it probably can't either (though it is a civil law question). But if a diagram is "creative" then it can be considered a "complete work" independent of the larger work in which it sits. For example, a paper might be completely captured in a single diagram (extreme case), in which case copying the diagram cannot be "fair use".

Comment: @CaptainEmacs: Much clearer, take a +1

Comment: This answer seems to focus on copyright, while the original question is about plagiarism - seems like a rather significant disconnect to me....

Comment: @DavidZ OP talks about medium transfer. I think others respond to the copyright issue more in detail, I emphasize the different aspects.

Answer (score 8):

Plagiarism is the act of taking someone else's work and passing it off as your own.

If this happens explicitly (i.e. you claim originality) then things are pretty clear cut.

The problem comes when you fail to clarify that a piece of work is not your own. Leaving the authorship of an idea ambiguous is where you get into trouble.

Thus, at a bare minimum, you need to give credit. Depending on what you're doing, this might be a formal citation, or a clear notice of the source. In a presentation, this might be an annotation on the slide or a clear verbal indication of where you got the idea.

Copyright takes things further. This moves from academic conduct into legal waters.

The specifics here depend on your country. Copying someone's work with appropriate citations may be covered by "fair use" clauses in your local copyright laws which permit copying work for the purposes of comment and criticism; as an educator, you have a good case that this is your purpose.

However, even then, you should be careful, especially if you're reaching a wide audience with your replication.

So, in summary:

- avoid charges of plagiarism by using appropriate forms of citation
- avoid charges of breaching copyright by understanding your local fair use exceptions.

Comment: As long as neither you nor anyone else is making money off of it, it's called *fair use*, +1.

Comment: @Mazura: Uh, that is not the definition of fair use. If I take a pre-released version of a film and share it on the web to allow others to watch it for free, that isn't [fair use](https://blogs.loc.gov/copyright/2018/02/knowing-when-you-can-use-a-copyrighted-work/)

Comment: "Fair use is the ability to use a work protected by copyright in certain circumstances, including for the purposes of comment, criticism, or teaching, **without first obtaining permission** from the rights holder. Determining whether a use is **fair is a case-by-case inquiry** and involves a hard look at the facts." - the definition of *fair use* is who has better lawyers.

Comment: @Mazura no it's not. There is a fairly precise legal definition of fair use. (What you quoted there is consistent with the definition, at least in the US, but your added commentary is not.)

Answer (score 1):

When I was writing a textbook, we had to be very careful about falling foul of copywrite issues with the figures we included. We had many figures that we cited as "adapted from..." or "inspired by....", and in those cases someone at the publisher looked carefully at how similar they were to the inspiration. In some cases our publisher decided they needed to seek permission from the copywrite holders and in some of those we had to pay a licensing fee, which was pretty large. I don't know to what extent our publisher was being defensive, and licensing things it didn't need to.

Answer (score 0):

Plagiarism existed long before computers and copy-pasting did. Do not confuse the means of copying with the act of plagiarism itself. If you reuse something (significantly large or important) without attribution, it is plagiarism. It doesn't matter if the original was jpeg, chalk, or stone tablets.

Copy-pasting an exact copy of a text or image is the kind of plagiarism that is easy to detect and prove, but if I were to read a brilliant but forgotten math thesis, understand the core elements, and then write them up differently and present them as my own, I would be the worst kind of plagiarist.

Comment: yes but diagrams seem somewhat different. Like, there are only so many ways someone can draw a sphere or a cube.

Comment: If the value of the diagram is in its design (either aesthetics or clarity, whatever you meant by "beautiful"), then this is what merits attribution.

Comment: if nothing of value is being used, then we might fall in the range of "not worth attributing"; again, regardless of _how_ the content is copied, in the sense that the question could have been answered the same way before computers.